# VeeValidate ValidationProvider "immediate" option not working with custom checkbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I am using Vue v2.7 and VeeValidate v3. I am having trouble getting the "immediate" option to work on my `ValidationProvider` that I have wrapped around a custom checkbox component. Here's a snippet:

```
<ValidationProvider
  ref="gam"
  v-slot="{ errors, failedRules }"
  :rules="{
    required: true
  }"
  immediate
>
  <AppCheckbox
    :label="availableIntegrationModules[0].text"
    v-model="gam"
    :disabled="disabled"
    :errors="!failedRules.required ? errors : []"
    name="gam"
  />
</ValidationProvider>
```

If I call the `.validate()` method provided by the `ValidationObserver` that I have wrapping the entire component before making any changes with this checkbox unchecked, it will return no validation errors, despite this field being marked as required. If I toggle the checkbox on and then off again, the validation starts working as expected and gives me the corresponding error.

According to the docs, the `immediate` option is supposed to solve this and essentially validate as soon as the component mounts, disregarding any "touched/dirty/pristine" states. This works well for custom input components I have elsewhere with a basically identical setup to this, but in the case of this custom checkbox component, it seems that the `immediate` option has no effect at all. Am I missing something here or is the library itself bugged?